# Knowing a set is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading about infinite sets and  "set is infinite if and only if for every natural number the set has a subset whose cardinality is that natural number". I was just wondering why that would be?

Comment: Suppose cardinality of a set is infinite. On contrary, assume that there is a natural number $n$ such that there is no subset of given set has cardinality $n$. Then cardinality of the set is less than or equal to $n$, which is not possible. Converse is clear.

Comment: Isn't this your definition of infinite set? Anyway, the tag "morse theory" is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Induct on $n$.  For $n = 1$, the set is nonempty, so is has a member $x$, and the subset $\{x\}$ has cardinality $1$.  If $A_n$ is a subset of cardinality $n$, there is some member $y$ not in $A_n$, and then $A_n \cup \{y\}$ is a subset of cardinality $n+1$.

Comment: You claim in a comment to another post that this proof doesn't use the Axiom of Choice. So how do you pick your $y$'s?

Comment: Axiom of choice is not needed to pick a single $y$, or finitely many, just to pick infinitely many.

Comment: But you have to do this for every $n$. You might have put it this way: " If $A_n$ is a subset of cardinality $n$, there is some member $y_n$ not in $A_n$."

Answer (score 0):

"$\Rightarrow$": If the set $A$ is infinite, then you can choose an infinite nonrepeating sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots \in A$. Now for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the set $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ has cardinality $n$.

"$\Leftarrow$": Suppose $A$ is finite. Then clearly $A$ does not have a subset of cardinality $|A|+1 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The existence of that sequence relies on the Axiom of Choice, which is not needed for my proof.

Comment: @RobertIsrael No it doesn't. You can construct such a sequence using induction, without needing even countable choice.

Comment: Well I think you're both wrong :-) Specifically, the words "choose an infinite nonrepeating sequence" immediately say "Axiom of Choice" to me.

Comment: See [Dedekind-infinite set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set)